# simplest way of converting an int to a string in C

Tags: c

I have been asked to perform some logic on an integer, which I think would be much more easier if I convert it to String. So please suggest me if there is a simple way other than 
using "sprintf" function in C

Comment: What is wrong with `sprintf` ?

Comment: There is itoa(), but not sure that's all that much simpler.

Comment: I don't think it gets much easier than `sprintf` - not in vanilla C. C++ has stringstreams and all that, and provides more syntax sugar to wrap conversions if you want to, but in C, I don't see an easier way.

Comment: Generally, C standard library functions will not dynamically allocate memory to return a result, so you probably won't find something with the signature `char *tostring(int)`

Comment: maybe you could share with us what logic you want to perform that is easier on a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only better way than `sprintf` is `snprintf`. For simple integer formatting it probably doesn't matter, but `snprintf` will protect you from disaster if you make a stupid assumption (for example, that `int` can't be more than 10 digits) or even a reasonable one (like `CHAR_BIT==8`)...

```
#define INT_DECIMAL_DIGITS (24*sizeof(int)/CHAR_BIT) // Safe upper bound
char buf[INT_DECIMAL_DIGITS+2]; // Optional sign and null termination
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", x);
```

Couldn't be much simpler...